# XSLT 1.0: Named template for multiple string substitution?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

**Problem in words**
I need to insert a string in other strings where I find a special string. The definition of these special strings are in a node-set. The closest generic solution would be to do a multiple replace and replace the matching special string with the inserted string concatenated with the special string. I have searched for a solution but not found any that work.

**Example.**
Input XML:

```
<root name ="theTop.">
    <string>Here are some silly words</string>
    <string>where I would like</string>
    <other>
        <string>to append other silly words</string>
    </other>
    <words>
        <word name="word"/>
        <word name="silly"/>
    </words>
</root>
```

Output XML:

```
<root name ="theTop.">
    <string>Here are some theTop.silly theTop.words</string>
    <string>where I would like</string>
    <other>
        <string>to append other theTop.silly theTop.words</string>
    </other>
    <words>
        <word name="word"/>
        <word name="silly"/>
    </words>
</root>
```

I haven't come up with anything usefull yet. This is a "sketch" of how I imagine how the skelleton could look like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="append" select="/root/@name"/>
<xsl:variable name="places" select="/root/words/word/@name"/>

<!--    Identity rule.-->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//string">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace-multiple">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$places"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="with" select="concat($append,$places)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Obvioulsy this doesn't work. It doesn't iterate the node-set $places and I have no named template replace-multiple to replace multiple different strings.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your input has e.g. `<words><word>word</word>` while your XSLT selects e.g. `/root/words/word/@name` so that doesn't make sense to me. And then the desired result has `<word name="word"/>`, do you want to transform those elements? Please clarify.

Comment: Ah, sorry. copy-paste error. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed quite difficult to do in XSLT 1.0.

The problem is not just replacing multiple strings. There is an additional complication here, because the replace-string contains the search-string (since you're only adding a prefix). This eliminates the possibility of using a single template to go repeatedly over the entire text, and dictates the use of two separate templates: one recursing over the multiple search-strings, and the other over the current search-string's occurrences in the text:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="string">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="multi-prefix">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="multi-prefix">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="search-strings" select="/root/words/word/@name"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$search-strings">
            <xsl:call-template name="multi-prefix">
                <xsl:with-param name="text">
                    <xsl:call-template name="single-prefix">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="search-string" select="$search-strings[1]"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="search-strings" select="$search-strings[position() > 1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="single-prefix">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="prefix" select="/root/@name"/>
    <xsl:param name="search-string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $search-string)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $search-string)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$prefix"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$search-string"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="single-prefix">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $search-string)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="search-string" select="$search-string"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [EXSLT](http://exslt.org/str/index.html) provides `str:replace`  (http://exslt.org/str/functions/replace/str.replace.template.xsl) for multiple replacements, however, I struggled to get it to simply replace the matched words with a simple string so I have overridden its implementation from using `copy-of` to `value-of`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl str"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:import href="http://exslt.org/str/functions/replace/str.replace.template.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template name="str:_replace">
        <xsl:param name="string" select="''"/>
        <xsl:param name="replacements" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($string)"/>
            <xsl:when test="not($replacements)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="replacement" select="$replacements[1]"/>
                <xsl:variable name="search" select="$replacement/@search"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(string($search))">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 1, 1)"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$replacement/node()"/>
                        <xsl:call-template name="str:_replace">
                            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring($string, 2)"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="replacements" select="$replacements"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($string, $search)">
                        <xsl:call-template name="str:_replace">
                            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-before($string, $search)"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="replacements" select="$replacements[position() > 1]"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$replacement/node()"/>
                        <xsl:call-template name="str:_replace">
                            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $search)"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="replacements" select="$replacements"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:call-template name="str:_replace">
                            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="replacements" select="$replacements[position() > 1]"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="string">
        <xsl:param name="insert" select="ancestor::root/@name"/>
        <xsl:param name="search" select="ancestor::root/words/word"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace">
            <xsl:for-each select="$search">
                <replace>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($insert, .)"/>
                </replace>          
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:param>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="str:replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="search" select="$search"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="exsl:node-set($replace)/replace"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```